# Cómo usar el onClick en un botón de un infowindow

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-hooks

Estoy usando react hooks con google-maps-react y tengo el siguiente infowindow con un botón dentro:

```
   <InfoWindow
          >
            <div> 
              <button 
              onClick={console.log('acá')}
               type="button" 
              >Ver Organización</button>
            </div>
          </InfoWindow>
```

Pero cuando le doy click al boton Ver Organización este no hace nada, alguien sabe por qué pasa eso?

Answer (score 1):

> En ReactJS se debe establecer una función en el atributo `onClick` por ejemplo una referencia, no llamar a una función.

La configuración actual de la propiedad `onClick` es para usar una referencia, así como esta se dispara en render time y no cuando se da click al botón:

```
onClick={console.log('acá')}
```

Se debe envolver dentro de una función flecha, para que ejecute solo cuando se da click al botón:

```
onClick={()=>console.log('acá')}
```

```js
function App(){
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={console.log('aca')}>Como ref</button>
      <button onClick={()=>console.log('aca')}>Como arrow</button>
    </div>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, pero sigue sin reconocer el evento.

Comment: Puse una demostración, por favor verifica de tu lado. Saludos